# What's all the ways to get "safe zones" where enemies don't spawn?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

I want safe zones so I can safely hunt for phones and toilet paper and shoes.

I've found two missions that do it, but are there more?

1. The "Scared Meter" section of "To Cure A Case of Scabs" has spawns turned off at the beginning.
2. The start of "This Ends Here".